# connect to mongodb on separate ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I am running two different instances on AWS, one for node application and other for mongoDB. I am trying to connect to mongoDB on other instance but not able to and failing with "504 Gateway timed out".

My db_conf.js to connect to node application is like below:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var url = "mongodb://<PUBLIC IP of mongoDB instance>:27017/local";

module.exports = url;
```

I have commented the "bind_ip" in mongodb.conf and restarted mongoDB.

Also, I have opened the port 27017 for the node application server's public IP from the security groups of mongoDB instance for both inbound and outbound but of no use.

Please suggest a way to achieve this(if there is any). Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All looks correct here, you do correctly open port 27017 on the mongoDB instance. Also, you may want to try and kill the original mongod server process, and restart it explicitly pointing to your config file so that it knows to use those settings. Something like the following should accomplish this (assuming your on a linux machine and your config file is in the default folder)-

> sudo kill mongod PID

and then

> sudo mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: You save my day!